# Error when using preload gorm golang, it's not running the preload table i need

Tags: go

I tried to learn and define a model in gorm golang
But i got this problem... dont know how to find the issue.
Firstly I have created 2 table name User and Schedule in database
this is the model

```
type User struct {
    UserId       int    `json:",omitempty" gorm:"primaryKey"`
    UserName     string `json:",omitempty"`
    UserPassword string `json:"-"`
    UserEmail    string `json:",omitempty"`
    UserFullName string `json:",omitempty"`
    Schedule []*Schedule `gorm:"foreignKey:UserId" json:"working_schedule"`
}
type Schedule struct {
    ScheduleId      int `gorm:"primaryKey"`
    ScheduleDate    int
    ScheduleStart   int
    ScheduleEnd     int
    ScheduleType    int
    ScheduleCreated int
    UserId          int
}
```

And i also do this code in golang for making an query to get all the schedule of specific user by the id i get.

```
Preload("Schedule").Table("user").Find(&user, "user_id=?", id)
```

But when showing the result at all the working_schedule is null. And I tried to debug the code above but only found that it just run a select from user... not in schedule

```
SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE user_id=1
```

Idk what I was wrong. Please help me. Ty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you named your struct `Schedule`, `go-gorm` will try to find a table named `schedules`, because it uses the pluralized `snake-case` convention. If it doesn't succeed, it will not create a query for it when doing preload.

If your database table is named `schedule`, you will have to implement the `Tabler` interface (maybe below the definition of your `Schedule` struct).

```
func (Schedule) TableName() string {
    return "schedule"
}
```

You can find more info on this [here](https://gorm.io/docs/conventions.html#TableName).

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your anwser... But in my database there is already have an database name schedule

Comment: I will modify my answer to work with the `schedule` database table name.

Comment: alright... so now it will find the table name: schedules right? and the thing i need is that implment the tabler to use? But when i use .Debug() there is nothing happen some kind like: cant find table `Schedules` etc.. So it's hard to know that the query is builded or not...

Comment: If your database table name is `schedule`, then you need this `Tabler` interface implementation. If the database name is `schedules`, then you don't need this implementation.

Comment: but when I alter table name to schedules. Then run the code again... it still like the previous result

Comment: One thing you could try is writing your query differently, like `Table("user").Preload("Schedule").Find(&user, "user_id=?", id)` or `Table("user").Preload("Schedule").First(&user, id)`. Second,  the issue might be with how the relationship between user and schedule is defined and if everything matches in terms of naming struct fields properly.

Comment: thanks for your advice. I would try that query... but any different between your query and mine? because I cant figure out how to show the second query in Preload like in the docs said